# Json.Net can't load the assembly

Tags: c#, .net, json.net

I'm trying to desarialize a simple json array and bind it a model like this:

**JSON**

```
[{
    "id": "311697",
    "km": "36.00",
    "start": "2015-12-07",
    "end": "2015-12-07",
}, {
    "id": "311697",
    "km": "36.00",
    "start": "2015-12-07",
    "end": "2015-12-07",
}]
```

**Model**

```
public class SalModel
    {
        public string id{ get; set; }
        public float km{ get; set; }
        public string start{ get; set; }
        public string end{ get; set; }
    }
```

And, to get the array I'm using:

```
var json = new WebClient().DownloadString(url);
```

At this time, the array is perfectly.

But, any time that I'm trying to use `json.net` library:
with methods like:

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<SalModel>>(json);
```

I can't debug this method, and I get an error like:

> Not is possible load the file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json'
>   Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' and
>   any of the dependencies. The assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the reference to the assembly.

Comment: TL;DR your versions don't match somewhere in your solution. You've prob get a reference in another project to an older version to Netwonsoft.Json

Comment: @MrMins check out a `GAC` old version is probably cached. also try to reinstall `Newtonsoft` Nuget package